# Screen-readers and changing text in Flash

Tags: flash, accessibility, screen-readers

I have a bunch of Flash files which I need to keep and make WCAG2 compliant. I can't get my screen-reader (NVDA) to read all of the content, and it doesn't show up when I look at it with aDesigner either.

The idea is that you click on a button to find out more information. The buttons can be reached and clicked with the keyboard. The text for that section should then appear. I've got the text sitting out of the main visible area, and on press/enter I bring it into the visible area. I assumed that screenreaders would just go through all the waiting text whether it was visible or not, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

The text is read just fine if it's on the visible portion of the stage when the reader starts. It's only new text that the reader won't acknowledge. Is it possible to notify the reader of the change, or put the text somewhere it can easily reach even if it's out of the way of sighted users?